# SQLServer alter database modify file questions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to re-set the database's log file initial size since it be miss set very big value (40G) when setting up the database. And when I want to shrink it, it will aslo be the size equal to the initial size.

I've tried to use this SQL with SIZE parameter to set:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'DBNAME_log', SIZE=1MB, MAXSIZE = 2048GB)
GO
```

Unfortunately, only got error message:

> MODIFY FILE failed. Specified size is less than or equal to current
>   size.

seems the size parameter need bigger than current size.

Here is the questions summarized:

1. How to re-set the database's file initial size? It need small enough regardless current file size.
2. I know my database name [DBNAME] and could get its related log file name using SQL :

   `DECLARE @logname NVARCHAR(100); SELECT @logname = name FROM sys.database_files WHERE type_desc = 'LOG'`

but why could **NOT** input database name using the result @logname, like:

```
ALTER DATABASE [OrderTracker] MODIFY FILE (*NAME = @logname*, size=1MB, MAXSIZE = 2048GB)
```

Comment: Did you make a backup before ? Backup is supposed to empty the log. (kind of)

Comment: did you look at this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/manage-the-size-of-the-transaction-log-file

Comment: I set the database to SIMPLE mode and use the SQL to shrink: DBCC SHRINKFILE (@logname, TRUNCATEONLY); It really be smaller but equal to or a bit larger than its initial size.

Comment: Shrinking without backing up before make no sense. RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

> How to re-set the database's file initial size? It need small enough regardless current file size

The ALTER DATABASE with MODIFY FILE command can only make a file size bigger, so if you need to make the file size smaller you need to use DBCC SHRINKFILE.

I wouldn't recommend shrinking,but if there is no way , you can use command like below

```
  dbcc shrinkfile('test_log_log',1)--we are asking to shrink log to 1 mb
```

if you have taken backups and log files are empty and VLF located at the end  of log is not active(2 is active,0 is inactive)..then you can shrink

you can use `dbcc loginfo` to know status of vlf and this should be run on same database

Comment: Thanks. I've tried, either DBCC SHRINKFILE (@logname, TRUNCATEONLY); nor DBCC SHRINKFILE (@logname, 1MB); worked! Only change the initial size VIA GUI worked but how to change via SQL? Could only re-set manually one by one is terrible for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you *cannot* Shrink below 2MB using `MODIFY FILE`.
There is *no* validation logic in `DBCC SHRINKFILE` when you pass in 0MB.
It just shrinks it to 1MB.  I think because you cannot increase 0MB's by 10%, so it defaults 0MB to 1MB.

The validation logic in `MODIFY FILE` will *not* allow you to set a size equal to the current-size (in this case 1MB).
Because of this, you *cannot* use anything less-than 2MB with `MODIFY FILE`.
BTW: 1MB is just *too* low for an `Initial Size` anyway.
Yes, you can set it to 1MB using the SSMS interface, but is a 1MB difference all that bad if you prefer to script it?

Here's an example of how to generate the scripts you'll run:

```
--Identify Log Files that Require Shrinking and Generate Scripts:
SELECT D.name[DatabaseName], F.name[FileName], F.physical_name[FilePath], F.type_desc[FileType],
       D.recovery_model_desc[RecoveryModel],
       (F.size * 8)[SizeKB], CAST((F.size * 8 / 1024.0) as Decimal(11,1))[SizeMB],
       ('USE ' + QUOTENAME(D.name) + ' DBCC SHRINKFILE (' + QUOTENAME(F.name) + ', 98)')[Shrink],
       ('ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(D.name) + ' MODIFY FILE (NAME = '
        + QUOTENAME(F.name) + ', SIZE = 100MB)')[Resize]
  FROM sys.master_files as F
  JOIN sys.databases as D
    ON D.database_id = F.database_id
 WHERE F.type_desc = 'LOG'
   --AND D.database_id > 4--Filter out System Databases. - 01/28/2020 - MCR.
   AND D.recovery_model_desc != 'FULL'--Shrink will not work on databases with Full Recovery.
   AND (F.size * 8 / 1024) > 100--Larger than 100MB's. - 01/28/2020 - MCR.
 ORDER BY D.name, F.name
```

I used 100MB as my Target File Size because we work with larger databases.
Do *not* use 99MB as your Shrink Size, because I found a rounding issue with SQL's validation,
    so always subtract -2 to determine your Shrink Size (in this case 98MB).

Note: If you are using the "***Full***" Recovery Model then you will need to Backup your Entire Database first, then Backup your Logs immediately after and they should automatically truncate.  Or, maybe Backup your Logs twice or as many times as necessary.